# Broken drawing program. Java

Tags: java

I am making a simple drawling program and the drawling panel will not show up. I don't know if it is a problem with the Circle class, or the drawingPanel class. The colorButtons and the sizeButtons do show up but the drawingPanel does not. Can you help me please, take your time and thanks in advance! P.S. I add the frames in the drawingFrame.

```
public class Assign72 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    DrawingFrame f= new DrawingFrame();
    f.setTitle("Drawing Program");
    f.setSize(462,312);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setVisible(true);
}

public class DrawingFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
private DrawingPanel drawPanel;
private JPanel panel;
private JPanel colorPanel;
private JPanel sizePanel;
private JRadioButton redRadioButton;
private JRadioButton blueRadioButton;
private JRadioButton greenRadioButton;
private JRadioButton blackRadioButton;
private JRadioButton smallRadioButton;
private JRadioButton mediumRadioButton;
private JRadioButton largeRadioButton;
private JButton eraseButton;
private ButtonGroup colorButtonGroup;
private ButtonGroup sizeButtonGroup;
final int SMALL = 4;
final int MEDIUM = 8;
final int LARGE = 10;

public DrawingFrame() {

    colorPanel = new JPanel();
    sizePanel = new JPanel();

    redRadioButton = new JRadioButton();
    redRadioButton.setText("Red");
    colorPanel.add(redRadioButton);
    redRadioButton.addActionListener(this);

    blueRadioButton = new JRadioButton();
    blueRadioButton.setText("Blue");
    colorPanel.add(blueRadioButton);
    blueRadioButton.addActionListener(this);

    greenRadioButton = new JRadioButton();
    greenRadioButton.setText("Green");
    colorPanel.add(greenRadioButton);
    greenRadioButton.addActionListener(this);

    blackRadioButton = new JRadioButton();
    blackRadioButton.setText("Black");
    colorPanel.add(blackRadioButton);
    blackRadioButton.addActionListener(this);



    smallRadioButton = new JRadioButton();
    smallRadioButton.setText("Small");
    sizePanel.add(smallRadioButton);
    smallRadioButton.addActionListener(this);

    mediumRadioButton = new JRadioButton();
    mediumRadioButton.setText("Medium");
    sizePanel.add(mediumRadioButton);
    mediumRadioButton.addActionListener(this);

    largeRadioButton = new JRadioButton();
    largeRadioButton.setText("Large");
    sizePanel.add(largeRadioButton);
    largeRadioButton.addActionListener(this);
    colorButtonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
    sizeButtonGroup = new ButtonGroup();

    sizeButtonGroup.add(smallRadioButton);
    sizeButtonGroup.add(mediumRadioButton);
    sizeButtonGroup.add(largeRadioButton);

    colorButtonGroup.add(redRadioButton);

    colorButtonGroup.add(blueRadioButton);
    colorButtonGroup.add(greenRadioButton);
    colorButtonGroup.add(blackRadioButton);

    redRadioButton.setSelected(true);
    largeRadioButton.setSelected(true);
    JPanel configurePanel = new JPanel();
    configurePanel.add(new JButton("Configure"));

    // Will be right-aligned.


    // The full panel.
    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);



    drawPanel = new DrawingPanel(Color.RED, LARGE);
    drawPanel.setBackground( Color.WHITE );



    this.add(sizePanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    this.add(colorPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

    this.add(drawPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);



}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (redRadioButton.isSelected())
        drawPanel.setCircleColor(Color.RED);
    if (greenRadioButton.isSelected())
        drawPanel.setCircleColor(Color.GREEN);
    if (blueRadioButton.isSelected())
        drawPanel.setCircleColor(Color.BLUE);
    if (blackRadioButton.isSelected())
        drawPanel.setCircleColor(Color.BLACK);
    if (smallRadioButton.isSelected())
        drawPanel.setCircleSize(SMALL);
    if (mediumRadioButton.isSelected())
        drawPanel.setCircleSize(MEDIUM);
    if (largeRadioButton.isSelected())
        drawPanel.setCircleSize(LARGE);

}
}

public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel implements MouseMotionListener {
private int circleSize;
private Color circleColor;
private Circle newCircle;
private Circle drawingCircle;

private ArrayList<Circle> circleArrayList = new ArrayList<Circle>();

DrawingPanel(Color colorValue, int size) {
    addMouseMotionListener(this);
}

public void setCircleColor(Color choice) {

}

public Color getCircleColor() {
    return circleColor;

}

public void setCircleDiameter(int diameter) {

}

public int getCircleSize() {
    return circleSize;

}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponents(g);
    Iterator<Circle> circleIterator = circleArrayList.iterator();
    Circle drawCircle;
    while (circleIterator.hasNext()) {
        drawCircle = (Circle) circleIterator.next();
        drawCircle.draw(g);
    }
}

public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event) {
    if (event.isMetaDown()) {
        newCircle = new Circle(getCircleSize(), event.getPoint(),
                this.getBackground());
        newCircle = new Circle(getCircleSize(), event.getPoint(),
                getCircleColor());
        circleArrayList.add(newCircle);
        repaint();

    }
}

@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}






   public class Circle {
private int size;
private Point point;
private Color color;

public Circle(int size, Point point, Color color) {
    setSize(size);
    setLocation(point);
    setColor(color);
}

public int getSize() {
    return size;

}

public void setSize(int size) {

}

public Point getLocation() {
    return point;

}

public void setLocation(Point point) {

}

public Color getColor() {
    return color;

}

public void setColor(Color color) {

}

public void draw(Graphics g) {
    getLocation();
    setColor(color);

    setSize(size);
    setColor(color);

    g.fillOval(point.x, point.y, size, size);

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you have code that's unwritten:

```
public void setCircleColor(Color choice) {

}
```

It should be obvious that `setCircleColor` *does nothing*. So the first thing you need to do is *finish writing the code*. Fill all those empty methods in:

```
public void setCircleColor(Color choice) {
    circleColor = choice;
}
```

Then your draw method doesn't set the color for the Graphics context so you need to do that:

```
public void draw(Graphics g) {
    //getLocation();
    //setColor(color);

    //setSize(size);
    //setColor(color);

    g.setColor(color);
    g.fillOval(point.x, point.y, size, size);
}
```

(And those other method calls don't serve a purpose.)

Then somewhere you need to be setting defaults for these values or else they start out as 0 and null.

```
DrawingPanel(Color colorValue, int size) {
    setCircleColor(colorValue);
    setCircleSize(size);
    addMouseMotionListener(this);
}
```

The last thing is your `mouseDragged` event has a few problems.

```
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event) {
    //if (event.isMetaDown()) {
        //newCircle = new Circle(getCircleSize(), event.getPoint(),
        //        this.getBackground());
        newCircle = new Circle(getCircleSize(), event.getPoint(),
                getCircleColor());
        circleArrayList.add(newCircle);
        repaint();

    //}
}
```

- `isMetaDown` may not be doing what you think it does. The meta key corresponds to the Mac 'Command' key and Windows 'Windows' key.
- You're creating `newCircle` twice. I'm not sure which one is supposed to be the 'correct' one. I would assume not the first one because the first one sets the Circle's color to the background color of the panel (in which case it will not be visible).

After those changes it seems to more or less work:

[image: Circles]

More notes:

- The lesson learned is that you can't expect incomplete code to do anything complete.
- You should read [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html). You should be creating your GUI on the EDT by wrapping the code in `main` with a call to `invokeLater`.
- Your code had compilation errors that you did not mention. Mainly that I had to change all the [inner classes to nested classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70324/java-inner-class-and-static-nested-class) and there were some method calls that appeared to be renamed at some point (eg `drawPanel.setCircleSize` appears it should be `drawPanel.setCircleDiameter`). When you post complete code examples they should be compilable unless the question is about a compilation error.

Here is the functioning code with all of those changes and a few minor others:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Assign72 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                DrawingFrame f= new DrawingFrame();
                f.setTitle("Drawing Program");
                f.setSize(462,312);
                f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static class DrawingFrame
    extends JFrame
    implements ActionListener {
        private DrawingPanel drawPanel;
        private JPanel panel;
        private JPanel colorPanel;
        private JPanel sizePanel;
        private JRadioButton redRadioButton;
        private JRadioButton blueRadioButton;
        private JRadioButton greenRadioButton;
        private JRadioButton blackRadioButton;
        private JRadioButton smallRadioButton;
        private JRadioButton mediumRadioButton;
        private JRadioButton largeRadioButton;
        private JButton eraseButton;
        private ButtonGroup colorButtonGroup;
        private ButtonGroup sizeButtonGroup;

        static final int SMALL = 4; // constants are static
        static final int MEDIUM = 8;
        static final int LARGE = 10;

        public DrawingFrame() {
            colorPanel = new JPanel();
            sizePanel = new JPanel();

            redRadioButton = new JRadioButton();
            redRadioButton.setText("Red");
            colorPanel.add(redRadioButton);
            redRadioButton.addActionListener(this);

            blueRadioButton = new JRadioButton();
            blueRadioButton.setText("Blue");
            colorPanel.add(blueRadioButton);
            blueRadioButton.addActionListener(this);

            greenRadioButton = new JRadioButton();
            greenRadioButton.setText("Green");
            colorPanel.add(greenRadioButton);
            greenRadioButton.addActionListener(this);

            blackRadioButton = new JRadioButton();
            blackRadioButton.setText("Black");
            colorPanel.add(blackRadioButton);
            blackRadioButton.addActionListener(this);

            smallRadioButton = new JRadioButton();
            smallRadioButton.setText("Small");
            sizePanel.add(smallRadioButton);
            smallRadioButton.addActionListener(this);

            mediumRadioButton = new JRadioButton();
            mediumRadioButton.setText("Medium");
            sizePanel.add(mediumRadioButton);
            mediumRadioButton.addActionListener(this);

            largeRadioButton = new JRadioButton();
            largeRadioButton.setText("Large");
            sizePanel.add(largeRadioButton);
            largeRadioButton.addActionListener(this);
            colorButtonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
            sizeButtonGroup = new ButtonGroup();

            sizeButtonGroup.add(smallRadioButton);
            sizeButtonGroup.add(mediumRadioButton);
            sizeButtonGroup.add(largeRadioButton);

            colorButtonGroup.add(redRadioButton);

            colorButtonGroup.add(blueRadioButton);
            colorButtonGroup.add(greenRadioButton);
            colorButtonGroup.add(blackRadioButton);

            redRadioButton.setSelected(true);
            largeRadioButton.setSelected(true);
            JPanel configurePanel = new JPanel();
            configurePanel.add(new JButton("Configure"));

            // Will be right-aligned.

            // The full panel.
            panel = new JPanel();
            panel.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

            drawPanel = new DrawingPanel(Color.RED, LARGE);
            drawPanel.setBackground( Color.WHITE );

            this.add(sizePanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
            this.add(colorPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

            this.add(drawPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (redRadioButton.isSelected())
                drawPanel.setCircleColor(Color.RED);
            if (greenRadioButton.isSelected())
                drawPanel.setCircleColor(Color.GREEN);
            if (blueRadioButton.isSelected())
                drawPanel.setCircleColor(Color.BLUE);
            if (blackRadioButton.isSelected())
                drawPanel.setCircleColor(Color.BLACK);
            if (smallRadioButton.isSelected())
                drawPanel.setCircleDiameter(SMALL);
            if (mediumRadioButton.isSelected())
                drawPanel.setCircleDiameter(MEDIUM);
            if (largeRadioButton.isSelected())
                drawPanel.setCircleDiameter(LARGE);
        }
    }

    public static class DrawingPanel
    extends JPanel
    implements MouseMotionListener {
        private int circleSize;
        private Color circleColor;
        private Circle newCircle;
        private Circle drawingCircle;

        private ArrayList<Circle> circleArrayList = new ArrayList<Circle>();

        DrawingPanel(Color colorValue, int size) {
            setCircleColor(colorValue);
            setCircleDiameter(size);
            addMouseMotionListener(this);
        }

        public void setCircleColor(Color choice) {
            circleColor = choice;
        }

        public Color getCircleColor() {
            return circleColor;
        }

        public void setCircleDiameter(int diameter) {
            circleSize = diameter;
        }

        public int getCircleSize() {
            return circleSize;
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponents(g);

            // use regular for loop
            for(Circle c : circleArrayList) {
                c.draw(g);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event) {
            newCircle = new Circle(getCircleSize(), event.getPoint(),
                    getCircleColor());
            circleArrayList.add(newCircle);
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0) {}
    }

    public static class Circle {
        private int size;
        private Point point;
        private Color color;

        public Circle(int size, Point point, Color color) {
            setSize(size);
            setLocation(point);
            setColor(color);
        }

        public int getSize() {
            return size;
        }

        public void setSize(int size) {
            this.size = size;
        }

        public Point getLocation() {
            return point;
        }

        public void setLocation(Point point) {
            this.point = point;
        }

        public Color getColor() {
            return color;
        }

        public void setColor(Color color) {
            this.color = color;
        }

        public void draw(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(color);
            g.fillOval(point.x, point.y, size, size);
        }
    }
}
```

There are plenty of other ways it could be improved but there are just too many suggestions to make. That will compile and perform.

Comment: Thanks you helped a ton. I learned a lot from reading through this and looking over your work!

Comment: @user3183590 please accept his answer if it has helped you

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your drawpanel exists there but is not painted.

It might be because it may not be opaque.

Try using `setOpaque(true);` on the drawpanel.

Comment: I just tried it didn't work.Thanks for the suggestion!